# How to create a grading scale in HTML using JavaSript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am just trying to get some help! I did my research but I couldn't find any helpful sources. This is my first time doing Java and I am not trying to get my homework solved; I am just trying to have a hint! so if there is anyone who can help me I would apprentice it!

This is my first time doing Java, and my teacher wants me to do grade scaling using JavaSript in HTML. However, he wants the result to appear in an alert. Like if the input is 90 then the page will alert "Grade is A"
He gave me an example but I need to add code to it and I am not sure what to add...Please guys help me

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function myFunction(){
         var x = document.getElementById("score").value;
         if (true) {
            alert("Hello World")
        }
}       
</script>
</head>

<body>  
    <p>Enter score in the box:</p>
    <input type="text" id="score">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add this

```
 if (x >= 90) {
  grade = "A";
  if (x >= 80) {
  grade = "B";
} //and so on//
```

Comment: If you can show your attempt, and the problem you have with it, we can help you concretely. As it stands now, it comes down to providing you a solution. Please research a bit. You'll need an `if` statement, compare values, ...etc.

Comment: I already know that. I am just trying to get some help. I did my research but I couldn't find any helpful sources. Like what I said, this is my first time doing Java and I am not trying to get my he solved. I am just trying to have a hint! s if there is anyone who can help me I would apprentice it!

Comment: You're not doing Java here. It's Javascript. Those two have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want an else if statement if that's how you're going to lay this out.  Though, I would recommend a switch in a case like this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

```
switch(expression) {
  case x:
    // code block
    break;
  case y:
    // code block
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

You'll probably want to confirm the value is numeric but this should be enough to get you started on the letter grade logic:

```
if (x >= 90){
    grade = "A";
}
else if (x >= 80) 
{
    grade = "B";
}
else if (x >= 70) 
{
    grade = "C";
}
else if (x >= 60) 
{
    grade = "D";
}
else{
    grade = "F";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet based on the answer of Nathan for the grade check.
I just changed the `alert()` action by a `console.log();`

```js
        let inputField, check,output;
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",initialize);
        function initialize(e){
            inputField = document.getElementById("score");
            check = document.getElementById("checkButton");
            output = document.getElementById("outputField");
            check.addEventListener("click",getScore);
        }
        function getScore(e){
            var score = inputField.value;
            var grade = returnGrade(score);
            output.value = "grade = " + grade;
            console.log("score = " + score + ", grade = " + grade);
        }  
        function returnGrade(x){
            var grade;
            if (x >= 90){
                grade = "A";
            }
            else if (x >= 80) 
            {
                grade = "B";
            }
            else if (x >= 70) 
            {
                grade = "C";
            }
            else if (x >= 60) 
            {
                grade = "D";
            }
            else{
                grade = "F";
            }
            return grade;
        }
```

```html
    <div>
        <p>Enter score in the box:</p>
        <input type="number" id="score" min="0" max="100" value="0">
        <button id="checkButton">click</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="outputField" type="text" disabled value="Grade">
    </div>
```

Comment: Ooops, 2020 sorry I didn't see the date!